# Removing PL/SQL Code from Oracle spool

Tags: oracle, plsql, spool

Executing the following code spools the PL/SQL code in the outputfile 'user.sql'. Is there a way to remove the PL/SQL code from the outputfile? Only the 'alter user ...' statements have to stay in the outputfile.

```
set serveroutput on
SET TERMOUT  OFF
SET ECHO     OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET LINESIZE 140
SET PAGESIZE 0

EXEC dbms_output.enable(NULL);
SPOOL user.sql

DECLARE
   vVersion   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   /* Check Version */
   SELECT version
     INTO vVersion
     FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION where product like '%Oracle Database 12c%';

   --
   /* loop through users */
   FOR i IN (SELECT *
               FROM DBA_USERS_WITH_DEFPWD)
   LOOP
      /* print a statement, based on vVersion, for the current user */
      IF (vVersion = '12.1.0.2.0')
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               'Alter user '
            || i.username
            || ' identified by values '
            || '''462368EA9F7AD215'''
            || ';');
      ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               'Alter user '
            || i.username
            || ' identified by values '
            || '''Invalid Password'''
            || ';');
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
SPOOL OFF
set serveroutput off
@user.sql
```

Example Output:

> SQL> DECLARE   2     vVersion   VARCHAR2 (100);   3  BEGIN   4     /*
>   Check Version */   5     SELECT version   6       INTO vVersion   7
>
>   FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION where product like '%Oracle Database
>   12c%';   8   9     --  10     /* loop through users */  11     FOR i
>   IN (SELECT *  12                 FROM DBA_USERS_WITH_DEFPWD)  13
>   LOOP  14        /* print a statement, based on vVersion, for the
>   current user */  15        IF (vVersion = '12.1.0.2.0')  16
>   THEN  17           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (  18                 'Alter
>   user '  19              || i.username  20              || ' identified
>   by values '  21              || '''462368EA9F7AD215'''  22
>   || ';');  23        ELSE  24           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (  25
>   'Alter user '  26              || i.username  27              || '
>   identified by values '  28              || '''Invalid Password'''  29 
>   || ';');  30        END IF;  31     END LOOP;  32  END;  33  / Alter
>   user GSMUSER identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215';
>   Alter user MDSYS identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215';
>   Alter user OLAPSYS identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215';
>   Alter user LBACSYS identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215';
>   Alter user ORDDATA identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215';
>   Alter user ORDSYS identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215';
>   Alter user DVF identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215';
>   Alter user SYSDG identified by values '462368EA9F7AD215'; ....

Comment: Can you put that code in a script and then run the script with `@` from the SQL prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL*Plus doesn't honour the `set echo off` for an interactive session. This is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG075):

> ECHO does not affect the display of commands you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus from the operating system.

If you paste that code into an SQL plus session you'll see that behaviour. You'll also see it if you do input redirection, e.g. from a Linux command line:

```
sqlplus user/passwd@tns < script.sql
```

You'll see lots of "SQL>" prompts echoed to your terminal as well, plus the alter statements.

You can either use the silent flag:

```
sqlplus -s user/passwd@tns < script.sql
```

or run as a script instead of interactively (though you need to add an `exit` at the end of the script, otherwise it'll appear to hang while it waits for you to type that):

```
sqlplus user/passwd@tns @script.sql
```

or both:

```
sqlplus -s user/passwd@tns @script.sql
```

The silent flag suppresses the SQL*Plus banners as well, so it will produce less clutter overall - though those don't go in the spool file anyway.

---

Not relevant to the question, but you don't need to spool the commands to a file and then run that as a script. You can just run the `alter` commands directly as dynamic SQL:

```
   LOOP
      IF (vVersion = '12.1.0.2.0')
      THEN
         execute immediate 'Alter user '
            || i.username
            || ' identified by values '
            || '''462368EA9F7AD215'''
            || ';');
      ELSE
         execute immediate 'Alter user '
            || i.username
            || ' identified by values '
            || '''Invalid Password'''
            || ';');
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
```